# ruby substring bug?

Tags: ruby, arrays, substring

I'm trying to find the first and second half of a string of numbers with ruby ignoring the central digit if the length is odd
i.e 
input = "102"
first_half = "1"
second_half = "2"

using this code

```
i = gets
first_half=i[0..(i.length / 2 - 1).floor]
second_half = i[i.length -first_half.length)..i.length - 1]
print "#{first_half}\n#{second_half}"
```

however for this input the output is
10 ("\n")
2

the code does however work correctly in irb. Can anyone see what the problem I have is??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = gets
```

returns the string with the newline character at the end, i.e. your string is `"102\n"`, thus has length 4.

Answer (score 1):

use `i=gets.chomp`

Answer (score 0):

```
i = gets.chomp
first_half=i[0..(i.length / 2 - 1).floor]
second_half = i[(i.length - first_half.length).. i.length - 1]
print "#{first_half}\n#{second_half}"

iano:Desktop ian$ ruby stack.rb 
102
1
2
```

Your problem (though there were some minor syntax errors) is that you have to chomp (removing the "\n" character at the end of the input string).